# Button not appearing in Swing GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

For my second programming assignment in my Java class, we have to create a Pizza Shop menu GUI. Everything appears on my GUI (including choices, boxes, radio buttons, etc.) except for the button ("Process Selection") you are supposed to click for calculating the total cost. The following is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PizzaShop extends JFrame {

    private Topping t;
    private PizzaSize ps;
    private PizzaType pt;
    private JPanel buttonPanel;
    private JButton ProcessSelection;

    public PizzaShop() {
        super("Welcome To Home Pizza Shop");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        t = new Topping();
        ps = new PizzaSize();
        pt = new PizzaType();
        createPanel();
        add(t, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(ps, BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(pt, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void createPanel() {
        buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        ProcessSelection = new JButton("Process Selection");
        ProcessSelection.addActionListener(new calButton());
        buttonPanel.add(ProcessSelection);
    }

    private class calButton implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            double subtotal;
            subtotal = t.getTopping() + ps.getPizzaSize();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your Order \n" + "Pizza Type" + pt.getPizzaType() + "\n" + "Amount Due" + subtotal);
        }
    }

    private class ExitButtonListener implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Did I forget to do add some code somewhere? I'm boggled.

Comment: Did you solve this? Can you please accept the answer which helped you the most

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not adding the `buttonPanel` to the main view

**UPDATE**: you should do this:

```
private void createPanel() {
    buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    ProcessSelection = new JButton("Process Selection");
    ProcessSelection.addActionListener(new calButton());
    buttonPanel.add(ProcessSelection);
    add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the button panel to the frame:

```
add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

Comment: to be precise `createPanel()` return type is `void`. You probably meant what Adel Boutros wrote

Answer (score 0):

Change your createPanel() to this:

```
private JPanel createPanel() {
    buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    ProcessSelection = new JButton("Process Selection");
    ProcessSelection.addActionListener(new calButton());
    buttonPanel.add(ProcessSelection);
    return buttonPanel;
 }
```

And add the code below to your PizzaShop() method:

```
add(createPanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

Or you can just follow what Adel Boutros said.